# Extracting Text that Beautiful Soup skips over using find_next _siblings /text not enclosed in tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to extract information from old classified pages online.  I mention this in particular because I can imagine that perhaps something has changed about HTML standards or something that may affect the way to do this.  It seems that part of the problem may be that text is not enclosed in any tags.

Here's an example of what the page HTML looks like:

```html
<h5>REAL ESTATE</h5>
<hr/><b>SANTA FE REALTOR</b> seeks culturally astute clients interested in relocation or second home. Contact Susan: <a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a> or PHONE

<hr/>
<h5>RENTALS</h5>
<hr/><b>NYC. GREENWICH VILLAGE.</b> Bed. Breakfast. Historic building, charming, great location. Short and long stays. PHONE or <a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a>.
<hr/><b>E. 71st &amp; PARK.</b> Quiet, beautiful, light-filled studio apartment. Available Wednesday-Sunday. Long-term. PHONE.
<hr/><b>BERKSHIRES—</b>extraordinary country home on swim pond with beach, 26 acres, 10 min. Tanglewood, large tiled hot tub, 4+BR, 4FPL, writer's cottage, AC, $10K/month, July–August; other months/year-round available. PHONE
<hr/><b>SPECTACULAR VIEW OVER MANHATTAN.</b> Furnished 1-bedroom apartment, quiet and secure, top floor upper East Side high-rise. $2,800 monthly, $800 weekly, minimum 2 weeks. PHONE or PHONE
<hr/><b>DEMOCRATIC CONVENTION—</b>Newly furnished ground floor one-plus bedrooms/one bath apartment on Beacon Hill; all conveniences, sleeps 1–4, easy walk to all central Boston. Photos available. $6K convention week, $9K month of July or best offer. <a href=“EMAIL”> EMAIL </a> or PHONE.

<hr/> <h5>INTERNATIONAL RENTALS</h5>
<hr/><b>SUPERB SABBATICALS</b> and vacation rentals: flats/houses, Paris, French countryside, Riviera, London, Tuscany, more; no exchanges. Two-week minimum. Over twenty years experience. <i> Abroad, Inc., Riverside Drive, New York, NY, tel . <a href=“website">website</a>.</i>
<hr/>
<b>CHARMING HOUSE—TODI, ITALY.</b> 4 bedrooms, fireplaces, garden, breathtaking views, parking. Tel:; fax: ; e-mail:
<a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a>.
<hr/><b>PARIS-MARAIS</b> Musée Picasso. Archives Nationales. Very attractive one bedroom, large living room, den, bathroom, kitchen, all appliances. Nonsmokers. Biweekly/monthly/sabbaticals. PHONE
```

What I want to do is extract the text of each listing in the RENTALS section as a separate items in a list.

It seems like this would be done by using some combination of parsing for the sibling elements of the header.

However when I run the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html')
target=soup.find("h5",text="RENTALS")
listingtext=[]
for sib in target.find_next_siblings():
    if sib.name=="h5":
        break
    elif not sib.text:
        pass
    else:
        listingtext.append(sib.text)
```

All that I get is list of all of the bold header text for the listings and the email addresses, which is all of the text enclosed in tags.
i.e.  I get:

```
["NYC. GREENWICH VILLAGE.","EMAIL",'E. 71st & PARK.', 'BERKSHIRES—','SPECTACULAR VIEW OVER MANHATTAN.','COLD SPRING, NEW YORK.', 'DEMOCRATIC CONVENTION—','EMAIL']
```

What I really would like is a list that looks like

```
['NYC. GREENWICH VILLAGE. Bed. Breakfast. Historic building, charming, great location. Short and long stays. PHONE or EMAIL','E. 71st & PARK. Quiet, beautiful, light-filled studio apartment. Available Wednesday-Sunday. Long-term. PHONE.' ... ]
```

It seems that the problem I'm having stems from the fact that the text is unenclosed and that affects how BeautifulSoup parses the text.  It also seems that I probably need to figure out how to use that the  tag,  which on the page was used to put lines between the listings, to delimit each listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to parse our info just from `'RENTALS'` section:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


txt = '''<h5>REAL ESTATE</h5>
<hr/><b>SANTA FE REALTOR</b> seeks culturally astute clients interested in relocation or second home. Contact Susan: <a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a> or PHONE

<hr/>
<h5>RENTALS</h5>
<hr/><b>NYC. GREENWICH VILLAGE.</b> Bed. Breakfast. Historic building, charming, great location. Short and long stays. PHONE or <a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a>.
<hr/><b>E. 71st &amp; PARK.</b> Quiet, beautiful, light-filled studio apartment. Available Wednesday-Sunday. Long-term. PHONE.
<hr/><b>BERKSHIRES—</b>extraordinary country home on swim pond with beach, 26 acres, 10 min. Tanglewood, large tiled hot tub, 4+BR, 4FPL, writer's cottage, AC, $10K/month, July–August; other months/year-round available. PHONE
<hr/><b>SPECTACULAR VIEW OVER MANHATTAN.</b> Furnished 1-bedroom apartment, quiet and secure, top floor upper East Side high-rise. $2,800 monthly, $800 weekly, minimum 2 weeks. PHONE or PHONE
<hr/><b>DEMOCRATIC CONVENTION—</b>Newly furnished ground floor one-plus bedrooms/one bath apartment on Beacon Hill; all conveniences, sleeps 1–4, easy walk to all central Boston. Photos available. $6K convention week, $9K month of July or best offer. <a href=“EMAIL”> EMAIL </a> or PHONE.

<hr/> <h5>INTERNATIONAL RENTALS</h5>
<hr/><b>SUPERB SABBATICALS</b> and vacation rentals: flats/houses, Paris, French countryside, Riviera, London, Tuscany, more; no exchanges. Two-week minimum. Over twenty years experience. <i> Abroad, Inc., Riverside Drive, New York, NY, tel . <a href=“website">website</a>.</i>
<hr/>
<b>CHARMING HOUSE—TODI, ITALY.</b> 4 bedrooms, fireplaces, garden, breathtaking views, parking. Tel:; fax: ; e-mail:
<a href=“EMAIL”>EMAIL</a>.
<hr/><b>PARIS-MARAIS</b> Musée Picasso. Archives Nationales. Very attractive one bedroom, large living room, den, bathroom, kitchen, all appliances. Nonsmokers. Biweekly/monthly/sabbaticals. PHONE'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for hr in soup.select('hr'):
    if hr.find_previous('h5') is None or hr.find_previous('h5').text != 'RENTALS':
        continue

    out, s = [], hr.next_sibling
    while not s is None and not (isinstance(s, Tag) and s.name in ('hr', 'h5')):
        if isinstance(s, Tag):
            out.append(s.get_text(strip=True))
        elif s.strip():
            out.append(s.strip())
        s = s.next_sibling

    if out:
        print(' '.join(out))
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
NYC. GREENWICH VILLAGE. Bed. Breakfast. Historic building, charming, great location. Short and long stays. PHONE or EMAIL .
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E. 71st & PARK. Quiet, beautiful, light-filled studio apartment. Available Wednesday-Sunday. Long-term. PHONE.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BERKSHIRES— extraordinary country home on swim pond with beach, 26 acres, 10 min. Tanglewood, large tiled hot tub, 4+BR, 4FPL, writer's cottage, AC, $10K/month, July–August; other months/year-round available. PHONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPECTACULAR VIEW OVER MANHATTAN. Furnished 1-bedroom apartment, quiet and secure, top floor upper East Side high-rise. $2,800 monthly, $800 weekly, minimum 2 weeks. PHONE or PHONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEMOCRATIC CONVENTION— Newly furnished ground floor one-plus bedrooms/one bath apartment on Beacon Hill; all conveniences, sleeps 1–4, easy walk to all central Boston. Photos available. $6K convention week, $9K month of July or best offer. EMAIL or PHONE.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

give the "url" you want to scrape and

i will edit this answer and gave you the correct way with the output also